# IF function would not return result as Pass but the Data is available

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have created a formula in Excel to return the result as "Pass" whenever the data is match as shown in image  [image: Sample]. The formula is as following

`"=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(D2,E2,F2,G2,H2),greenlist_level1!P:P,1,FALSE)>0,"Pass",IF(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(D2,E2,F2,G2,H2),greenlist_l2!P:P,1,FALSE)>0,"Pass","Not Available")),"Not Available")"`

Based on the formula , I have created a new column as a unique ID by using Concatenate on each of the worksheet as shown in this two image from different worksheet `level1` [image: level1] and `level2` [level2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w6ro.png)

As you can see both data exist on different worksheet. Why does my formula list the first item as "Not Available"? Is there a criteria that i missed.

Any help would be grateful

Comment: Please add screen shots with column and row numbers. Evaluation of formula cannot be done on assumptions.

Comment: Not an answer, but to prevent possible false positives, don't just concatenate text. Either use delimiters, or another construct. Simple example: `US` & `A` is the same as `U` and `SA`. I guess in your very example it's not going to be problematic quickly due to the amount of columns you concatenate.

Comment: @NareshBhople Thank you for the feedback , I have expand the screenshot to make it more clearer. The reason i filter to make it more easier viewing

Comment: @JvdV I have try using delimiters but due to the amount of columns . I choose to concatenate . As of now , it only detect one part of worksheet to be able to check true or false statement

Comment: Tried evaluating formula. The first if condition returns #N/A, and hence it applies iferror formula and returns "Not Available"  .. Try this formula `IF(AND(ISNA(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(D2,E2,F2,G2,H2),greenlist_level1!P:P,1,FALSE)),ISNA(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(D2,E2,F2,G2,H2),greenlist_l2!P:P,1,FALSE))),"Not Available","Pass")`

Comment: @NareshBhople Perhaps that should be an answer?  (The principle here being that `=IFERROR(IF(NA(),"True","False"),"Error")` will return `"Error"`)

Comment: I think you import your data from anywhere, try to TRIM(CLEAN()) every concatenated string. Example ```TRIM(CLEAN(D2))```

Comment: @Chronocidal .. Pardon my confusion. Do you mean, I should post that comment as an answer or is it incorrect with the principle you quoted? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try formula auditing? There you can see which part of your formula is not working correctly.

Comment: @NareshBhople Your comment is the correct answer - I was just explaining *why* it is the correct answer for OP's sake.  Write it up in full, then we can upvote it and OP can accept it!

Comment: @Chronocidal .. sorry for the confusion, posting it as an answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried evaluating OP's formula. The first if condition returns #N/A, and hence it applies iferror formula and returns "Not Available" ..

The logic behind this is well explained by Chronocidal  in his comments to the question as below.

`=IFERROR(IF(NA(),"True","False"),"Error")` will return `"Error")`

Try this formula

```
=IF(AND(ISNA(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(D2,E2,F2,G2,H2),greenlist_level1!P:P,1,FALSE)),ISNA(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(D2,E2,F2,G2,H2),greenlist_l2!P:P,1,FALSE))),"Not Available","Pass")
```

It will check if the value does not exists on both the sheets (with AND condition) then "Not Available" else "Pass"